# What gulp plugin should I use to build ASP.NET 5 on Mac?

Tags: c#, macos, asp.net-mvc-5, gulp, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code docs https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/tasks provides an example of gulp task for building c# code.

```
var program = "MyApp";
var port = 55555;

gulp.task('default', ['debug']);

gulp.task('build', function() {
    return gulp
        .src('./**/*.cs')
        .pipe(msc(['-fullpaths', '-debug', '-target:exe', '-out:' + program]));
});

gulp.task('debug', ['build'], function(done) {
    return mono.debug({ port: port, program: program}, done);
});
```

But there is no info about gulp plugin.
Can I build my aspVnext app with gulp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET 5 (vNext) apps are not "built" per se. Read the wiki to learn more about how to use `dnx` and `dnu` commands:

[ASP.NET Wiki: Command line](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Command-Line)

[ASP.NET Wiki: DNX Utility](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-utility)

You could use [gulp shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell) to run these commands